# Regular Expression that doesn't match when a certain character appears after another specific character?

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that does not match when a character exists in string after a specific character.

For example my first character is 'X' and the character that is no allowed after is 'U'.

Following is valid:

```
eUpXssseeeree // U is before X
rtsssXeeeree  // U is not there at all
```

Following is NOT valid

```
ereXUppsrrrsssss     // U is there right after X
ereeXrerrrtogUoosss  // U is still there even after a few characters
```

I'm using C# syntax.  Can you guide me on how to write such a regular expression?

Comment: What should happen in the case where `X` is not in the string at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it could be as straightforward as "any characters, followed by `X`, followed by any characters that aren't `U`":

```
/^.*X[^U]*$/
```

(see [reFiddle example](http://refiddle.co/1fj))

Of course, you want to make sure to match the entire string by using start `^` and end `$` characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
string testString = "eUpXssseeeree";

if ( !Regex.IsMatch( testString , @"[X].*[U]") )
{
     //Valid case
     //eUpXssseeeree // U is before X  
     //rtsssXeeeree  // U is not there at all
}
else
{
//Invalid Case
}
```

Comment: +1 for a different yet equally valid way to approach it (i.e., matching invalid cases instead of valid cases)

Comment: @wiseguy - More than valid, its correct as the expression checks for the negative of a specific match. Unlike yours, gavin conditional will pass if *no* X is in the string, which is the other factor.

Comment: @sin I didn't see such a requirement one way or the other. I wrote that "it could be as straightforward as" the expression I provided so as to leave room for any additional requirements the asker had not shared, such as the one you are suggesting. More info is necessary to make a determination.

Comment: @wiseguy - I probably don't think so. In that case, having X be there would be a primary requirement before the specific NOT case.

Comment: @gavin: Your solution is correct but it needs C#, C ..., that I didn't even tag question for them, I needed a pure regular expression :)